# How To Grab data from this String output - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have below output.

<class 'str'>

```
[{
    "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
    "Description": "Primary network interface",
    "DeviceIndex": 0,
    "Groups": ["sg-0b11476a38d83dba3", "sg-80e269f9"],
    "Ipv6AddressCount": 0,
    "Ipv6Addresses": [],
    "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-45fe4079",
    "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.38.42",
    "PrivateIpAddresses": [{
        "Primary": true,
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.38.42"
    }],
    "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount": 0,
    "SubnetId": "subnet-3d03d94b",
    "InterfaceType": "interface",
    "Ipv4Prefixes": [],
    "Ipv6Prefixes": []
}]
```

And I want to print in two lines

```
"Groups":

["sg-0b11476a38d83dba3", "sg-80e269f9"]
```

How can i do that in python?

I am trying to understand how to parse AWS API outputs in boto3 to build some automation. Is there any specific resource I can study that can help me master parsing AWS / Boto3 API in python?

Comment: If that's a string, then you need to convert that to a JSON and then access the first index of the array, which is a dictionary, and then grab the "Groups" key and its value.

Comment: `obj = json.loads( data )` / `print( obj[0]['Groups'] )`.  You just need to read a bit about JSON.  Most web APIs return JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
txt = """
[{ "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true, "DeleteOnTermination": true, "Description": "Primary network interface",
"DeviceIndex": 0, "Groups": ["sg-0b11476a38d83dba3", "sg-80e269f9"], "Ipv6AddressCount": 0, "Ipv6Addresses": [],
"NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-45fe4079", "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.38.42", "PrivateIpAddresses":
[{ "Primary": true, "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.38.42" }], "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount": 0, "SubnetId":
"subnet-3d03d94b", "InterfaceType": "interface", "Ipv4Prefixes": [], "Ipv6Prefixes": [] }]
"""

d = json.loads(txt)
>>> d
[{'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
  'DeleteOnTermination': True,
  'Description': 'Primary network interface',
  'DeviceIndex': 0,
  'Groups': ['sg-0b11476a38d83dba3', 'sg-80e269f9'],
  'Ipv6AddressCount': 0,
  'Ipv6Addresses': [],
  'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-45fe4079',
  'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.38.42',
  'PrivateIpAddresses': [{'Primary': True,
    'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.38.42'}],
  'SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount': 0,
  'SubnetId': 'subnet-3d03d94b',
  'InterfaceType': 'interface',
  'Ipv4Prefixes': [],
  'Ipv6Prefixes': []}]
```

and

```py
>>> d[0].get('Groups')
['sg-0b11476a38d83dba3', 'sg-80e269f9']

# or (for all elements in the list)

>>> [di.get('Groups') for di in d]
[['sg-0b11476a38d83dba3', 'sg-80e269f9']]
```

BTW, you'll definitely benefit by using `boto3` instead of AWS cli for scripts etc. For quick things on the command line, AWS cli is awesome. When you start to want to do some real automation around AWS services, I find `boto3` + `Python` hard to beat.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, Yes I am writing boto3 / lambda. I am not a programmer but with Network Guy. Trying to learn some Python/Boto3 with AWS API. I can parse basic output , but i struggle sometime due to weak basics. If you can refer some good resource to parse AWS API output then please do share.  Or I just learn how to Parse dictionaries in Python and should be good to go ?

Comment: For some things, using [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/tutorial/) on the JSON output of `awscli` commands can be a life-saver.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

data = '''
[{ "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true, "DeleteOnTermination": true, "Description": "Primary network interface", "DeviceIndex": 0, "Groups": ["sg-0b11476a38d83dba3", "sg-80e269f9"], "Ipv6AddressCount": 0, "Ipv6Addresses": [], "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-45fe4079", "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.38.42", "PrivateIpAddresses": [{ "Primary": true, "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.38.42" }], "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount": 0, "SubnetId": "subnet-3d03d94b", "InterfaceType": "interface", "Ipv4Prefixes": [], "Ipv6Prefixes": [] }]
      ''' # wrap in a string



parsed_data = json.loads(data)
groups = parsed_data.get("Groups", [])
```